# Inheriting singular controller with render helper

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to render a set of tabs for a set of objects (conversations) using the render helper for each. This is not part of a route as it is a persistent part of the interface. I have run into a problem where only the view with the same name as the model gets the intended controller (i.e. the panel contents and not the tab headers).

I have a Chat model, object controller and array controller (deliberately simplified here):

```
App.Chat = DS.Model.extend({ });

App.ChatsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  content: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentChats'),
});

App.ChatController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ });
```

The ArrayController needed the needs/content properties because the chats are loaded in the application controller. I used the currentChats name as other routes may load non-current chats.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function(){
    this.store.find('chat', {"current": true});
    this.set('currentChats', this.store.all('chat'));
  }
});
```

I have no difficulty rendering the chat contents with the appropriate controller (into the 'chat' template). However, the chat tabs are given the default ObjectController, and therefore can't fire actions.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
    <!--application template-->
    {{outlet chats}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="chats">
<div id="chats">
  <ul id="chat-tabs">
    {{#each}}
        {{render 'chatTab' this}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{#each}}
    {{render 'chat' this}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="chatTab">
<!--tab template-->
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="chat">
    <!--chat template-->
</script>
```

The application router is as follows:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){ },
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this.render('application', { });
        this.render('chats', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'chats',
            controller: 'chats'
        });
    }
});
```

This seems to come solely down to naming of the templates. The template called 'chat' inherits the correct controller, but chatTab doesn't despite receiving a chat as the model. Is there any way to force the view to inherit the correct controller? Or am I going about this in an idiosyncratic way.

Many thanks for your help to this Ember novice.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes solely off the name provided to the render.  The easiest way is to just create the other controller and extend the chat controller.

```
App.ChatTabController = App.ChatController.extend();
```

Comment: That is absolutely terrific! Makes so much sense now I know. Thanks for your help.